# When reading a file line by line, how to add an element to an array?

Tags: c#, file

I need to read the file *line by line* (each line contains an *integer* number), *parse* it from line to number and then, most importantly, **ADD ELEMENT to the array**!
I leave a piece of code

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader (@"input.txt", System.Text.Encoding.Default))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine ())! = null) 
    {
        //TODO: Add the element somehow
    }
}
```

P.S. I apologize in advance for my English). Thanks to all

Comment: See my answer at following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980456/reading-from-a-text-file-in-c-sharp

Comment: For the general related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32810535/how-to-read-numbers-in-a-txt-file-to-an-integer-array, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27467321/how-to-read-integers-from-a-text-file-to-array.

Comment: Can you give an example of the input.txt file's content and the expected result

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you right, you can get rid of `Stream`, but add a simple *Linq* to `File.ReadLines`:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

... 

int[] result = File
  .ReadLines(@"input.txt")
  .Select(line => int.Parse(line)) 
  .ToArray();
```

If you want to add records from file to *existing* array, you can try `Concat`:

```
int[] existingData = ...

...

existingData = existingData
  .Concat(File
           .ReadLines(@"input.txt")
           .Select(line => int.Parse(line))) 
  .ToArray();
```